# angularjs cache & restore templates - is this possible?

Tags: angularjs, caching

I'm still new into angularjs and would like to know if its possible to realize my sketch with.

Basically I want to cache templates (minimize) so the user can switch to another template without loosing the content.

scenario:
User is writing customer data in template1 but needs some information from template2. template1 gets cached and template2 shows up. User closes template2 and gets back to template1 where he can continue writing.

Thanks a lot,
kornel

[image: sketch]

Comment: `ng-show="" ` or a service, or,... This feature would also be easy to make with jQuery.

Comment: just for clarification: your title is misleading, since you are not talking about "Templates" here - you want to cache way more than just the template. you want to cache the user input, etc as well. you should think about editing your title